# What metrics can be used to describe the clustering of a group of points?

Tags: data-analysis, clustering, data-mining, data-structure

Consider a set of points $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (to make it simple, consider $n=2$). So you basically have a bunch of points on a plane.

I need to find good metrics that can describe the closeness, clustering of this dispersion of points. Scalar quantities is what I am looking for, in order to answer these questions:

- Are the points forming a single compact mass?
- Are the points quite uniformly distributed across the plane?
- Are the points generating some clusters?

  - If so, are they arranged in many clusters? Few clusters?

Comment: It looks like you are asking about [data mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining). This is a huge area of science and there are lots of algorithms, including machine learning.

Comment: @freakish It is precisely that, however the nature of the question is not intrinsically related to ML only, it is Mathematically very generic, hence I asked it here and not in Cross-Validated.

Comment: what I've meant is that this question is too broad.